# Flexslider Multiple Sliders in IE7 not showing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, slideshow, flexslider

I'm trying to get  multiple slideshows on one page to work however IE7 isn't playing ball.

I've made sure that my jQuery has no trailing ',' at the end of the options and I've also tried jQuery 1.7.2, 1.9, and the latest 1.10.

My html:

```
<div class="flexslider slidegallery">
   <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="images/XXXXXXXX.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/XXXXXXXX.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/XXXXXXXX.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="flexslider slidegallery2">
       <ul class="slides">
          <li><img src="images/XXXXXXXX.jpg" alt="" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/XXXXXXXX.jpg" alt="" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/XXXXXXXX.jpg" alt="" /></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.slidegallery').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: false
    });
    $('.slidegallery2').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: true,
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        slideshow: false
    });
```

I have a total of 3 slideshows - two running on 'slidegallery' and one using 'slidegallery2'. The first gallery ('slidegallery') will show up but the other two won't.

When I remove the first gallery the second  gallery will work. Has anyone stumbled upon this problem before?

**EDIT:
I'm going to assume it is some sort of bug. In the end I used a previous version of flexslider.js (v2.0) whereas before I was using the latest (v2.2) version.
Once I downgraded the JS file IE7 was working correctly as it should with multiple slideshows. Hope this helps someone.**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Multiple sliders don't work in IE7, only the first is shown. This bug is in version 2.2.2 but is not in 2.1. I compared both scripts line-by-line and found the code, that is responsible for this bug. Here it is in jquery.flexslider.js:

```
slider.find("img").attr("draggable", "false");
```

In jquery.flexslider-min.js it is:

```
r.find("img").attr("draggable","false");
```

Deleting this line fix the problem. Glad it helps.